# Writing a python program that first adds the entered value then check if the new value is prime or not

Tags: python

I am trying to write a program in Python that will:

1. Add the input. Say input is 123 it will add it and give output (1+2+3) 6
2. Check if output (6) is prime or not

This is what I have been doing but it doesn't seem to work for number above 10 which need to perform addition first.

```
def prime_digit_sum(number):
    n = (number)
    temp = n = int(n) 
    remainder = sum = 0 
    while (  temp > 0) :
            remainder = temp % 10
            temp = temp/10
            sum= sum +remainder

    if number == 2:
        return 1
    elif number == 3:
        return 1
    if number <= 1 or number%2==0:  
        return 0  
    check=3  
    maxneeded=number  
    while check<maxneeded+1:  
        maxneeded=number/check  
        if number%check==0:  
            return 0  
        check+=2  
    return 1  

while(True):
    text = input("please enter an integer: ")
    if (text == 'q'):
        break
    number = int(text)

    result = prime_digit_sum(number)
    if (result == None):
        continue
    if result:
        print("the sum of digits of", number, "is a prime number")
    else:
        print("the sum of digits of", number, "is not a prime number")

    print()

print("exiting")
```

Comment: So what doesn't it do? Have you debugged your code?

Comment: its working... what is problem??

Comment: The problem is it is not adding the input digits... say if I input 123 it should first add those digits which should give a number "6" and then this new number is prime or not has to be determined. Right now the program is only determining prime or not for the input not the sum of input

Comment: If you search SFO or wikipedia you can find some examples for checking whether a number is prime. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test is probabilistic but generally a good choice.